# Ultragrid entire column selection when header is clicked

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

This might seem a very easy problem but I am stuck and can't find a way out of it. I am using ultragrid in my form with several columns. My issue is when I am trying to click on the column header I am expecting my entire column to be selected but it doesn't. I assumed the SelectTypeCol is the property for my column selection but it did not work either. I also tried to add each column to Selected.Columns collection like this UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(i).Header.Selected = True but it didn't work for me either. I believe Selected is only available during runtime but not at the design mode.

So if there is an easier way to make this work, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the property `HeaderClickAction`

```
 grid.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderClickAction = HeaderClickAction.Select
```

This will automatically flip the selection state of the entire column as Selected (or Delected) when you click on the header. Of course this means also that you loose the ability to automatically sort on all columns

You can programmatically set the Selection state of a column with code like this  (C#)

```
 grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["youColumnKey"].Header.Selected = true;
```

this will permit to leave the `HeaderClickAction` property to `SortSingle` or `SortMulti`, but you have to handle the situation using code and appropriate events

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an InitializeLayout event on your grid.  in this event you need to set the chekboxsynchronization to default and it should work here is sample code

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender,
                                             Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Add("CheckBox");
        e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["CheckBox"].Style = ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
        e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["CheckBox"].Header.CheckBoxVisibility = HeaderCheckBoxVisibility.WhenUsingCheckEditor;
        e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["CheckBox"].Header.CheckBoxSynchronization = HeaderCheckBoxSynchronization.Default; <-- make sure it is set to default here
    }
```